# Flac playback in Iceweasel

Tags: debian, firefox, iceweasel, flac

Which package provides Flac support in Iceveasel on Debian Wheezy? At http://hpr.dogphilosophy.net/test/ all test clips work except the Flac file.

Comment: [flac codecs in firefox](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=2268617) Apparently it is possible (see the link). I was looking for the same thing, but this solution I found is too technical for me, so I didn't try it myself. Maybe it helps you though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I or anyone here or in newsgroup `linux.debian.user` know there is no such package in the Debian Wheezy repositories.